# Intent from Fragment to Activity

Tags: android, xml, android-fragments, fragment

I was trying to go to another page using `button`, but it always fail.

**Here is my First Class with its XML:**

```
public class FindPeopleFragment extends Fragment {
    public FindPeopleFragment(){}

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);
        return rootView;
    }

    public void goToAttract(View v)
    {
        Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity().getApplication(), MainActivityList.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

**Here is my XML:**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >
<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="48dp"
    android:onClick="goToAttract"
    android:text="Button" /></RelativeLayout>
```

Here is my stacktrace..this is the result when i used onclicklistener

```
12-30 16:54:28.006: E/AndroidRuntime(992): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-30 16:54:28.006: E/AndroidRuntime(992): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{info.androidhive.slidingmenu/info.androidhive.slidingmenu.MainActivityList}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #7: Error inflating class <unknown>
12-30 16:54:28.006: E/AndroidRuntime(992):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1955)
12-30 16:54:28.006: E/AndroidRuntime(992):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1980)
12-30 16:54:28.006: E/AndroidRuntime(992):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:122)
12-30 16:54:28.006: E/AndroidRuntime(992):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1146)
12-30 16:54:28.006: E/AndroidRuntime(992):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
12-30 16:54:28.006: E/AndroidRuntime(992):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
12-30 16:54:28.006: E/AndroidRuntime(992):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4340)
12-30 16:54:28.006: E/AndroidRuntime(992):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-30 16:54:28.006: E/AndroidRuntime(992):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
12-30 16:54:28.006: E/AndroidRuntime(992):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
12-30 16:54:28.006: E/AndroidRuntime(992):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
12-30 16:54:28.006: E/AndroidRuntime(992):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
12-30 16:54:28.006: E/AndroidRuntime(992): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #7: Error inflating class <unknown>
12-30 16:54:28.006: E/AndroidRuntime(992):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:606)
12-30 16:54:28.006: E/AndroidRuntime(992):  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:56)
12-30 16:54:28.006: E/AndroidRuntime(992):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:653)
12-30 16:54:28.006: E/AndroidRuntime(992):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:678)
12-30 16:54:28.006: E/AndroidRuntime(992):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:
```

Comment: getActivity().getApplication() should be getActivity() to begin with

Comment: pardon? i dont get your point.

Comment: Intent() need an activity instance, and a class, so GetActivity() for the instance and ClassName.class for the class. Getapplication() return an instance of the Application variable.

Comment: @user3138250 have you tried the code provided by raghunandan?

Comment: @KanwaljitSingh yes, still it doesnt work with my problem

Comment: what is the name of your xml file you provided above?

Comment: @KanwaljitSingh **fragment_home**

Answer (score 62):

use this

```
public void goToAttract(View v)
{
    Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), MainActivityList.class);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

be sure you've registered `MainActivityList` in you Manifest

Comment: above already..in XML i used the **android:onClick"method_name"**
and in java fragment class i have the method **"goToAttract"**

Comment: @user3138250 refer to raghunandan's answer

Comment: Sir, you should have put **be sure you've registered MainActivityList in you Manifest** first. Thanks. Finally working.

Answer (score 6):

Try this code once-

```
public class FindPeopleFragment extends Fragment {

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
      Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home,
        container, false);
        Button button = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.button1);
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
        updateDetail();
        }
        });
        return rootView;
        }

public void updateDetail() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), MainActivityList.class);
        startActivity(intent);
        }
}
```

And as suggested by Raghunandan remove below code from your `fragment_home.xml`-

```
android:onClick="goToAttract"
```

Comment: your code, try to intend it correctly it does not look well

Answer (score 3):

Remove this

```
android:onClick="goToAttract"
```

Then

```
View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);
Button b = (Button)rootView.findViewById(R.id.button1);
b.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
{
     public void onClick(View v)
     {
        Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), MainActivityList.class);
        startActivity(intent);

     } 

});
return rootView;
```

The error says you need to `public void goToAttract(View v)` in Activity class

```
Could not find method goToAttract(View) in the activity class
```

Reason pls check the answer by PareshMayani @

[Android app crashing (fragment and xml onclick)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14139774/android-app-crashing-fragment-and-xml-onclick)

Edit:

```
Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
```

I guess you have a image that is too big to fit in and it needs to be scaled down. Hence the `OutOfMemoryError`.

Comment: are you sure that i dont need to do this "Button b = **(Button)** rootView.findViewById(R.id.button1);"

i get error without that and after running with that i get this error [link](http://i.stack.imgur.com/pj1sh.png)

Comment: @user3138250 yess you need to cast it to button. it was a typo error

Comment: @user3138250 pls post the stack trace instead of posting links to snap shots. No way we can guess what's happenning without seeing the stacktrace. If you keep posting links i don't think i willwaste my time looking at snap shots

Comment: @KanwaljitSingh i rolled back the edit bcoz i din't find anything that needed substantial edit to my post

Comment: @user3138250 why did you re-edit your post without stacktrace. OutOf Memory generally occurs bcoz you have image that is too large to fit in.

Comment: @Raghunandan but i am not using image.

Comment: @AndroidNewbie might be using somewhere in your app. Are you sure.

Answer (score 3):

in your receiving intent use as

```
Intent intent = getActivity().getIntent();
        ((TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.hello)).setText(intent.getStringExtra("Hello"));
```

and in your send intent

```
Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(),Main2Activity.class);
        intent.putExtra("Hello","Nisar");
        getActivity().startActivity(intent);
```

remember both are in fragments

Answer (score 3):

use **getContext()** instead of MainActivity.this

```
Intent intent = new Intent(getContext(), SecondActivity.class);
startActivity(start);
```

Answer (score 2):

Hope this code will help

```
public class ThisFragment extends Fragment {

public Button button = null;
Intent intent;

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.yourlayout, container, false);

    intent = new Intent(getActivity(), GoToThisActivity.class);
    button = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.theButtonid);
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
    return rootView;
}
```

You can use this code, make sure you change "**ThisFragment**" as your fragment name, "**yourlayout**" as the layout name, "**GoToThisActivity**" change it to which activity do you want and then "**theButtonid**" change it with your button id you used.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use getActivity() method from fragment for Intents.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), SecondActivity.class);
startActivity(intent);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 FragmentManager fragmentManager =  getFragmentManager();
 fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.frame, new MySchedule()).commit();
```

MySchedule is the name of my java class.

Answer (score 1):

For Kotlin you can use

```
val myIntent = Intent(activity, your_destination_activity::class.java)
startActivity(myIntent)
```

Comment: Hi, I tried this and now getting error Unresolved reference for your_destination_activity (in my case RegistrationActivity). Do I need to import it in fragment? When making an intent from 1 activitie to another, I don't need an import, is it different for fragments? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If you can get a `View` in that fragment, you can access the context from there:

```
view.getContext().startActivity(intent);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
public class OneWayFragment extends Fragment {

    ImageView img_search;


public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {


        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.one_way_fragment, container, false);
        img_search = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.search);


        img_search.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override`enter code here`
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent displayFlights = new Intent(getActivity(), SelectFlight.class);
                startActivity(displayFlights);
            }
        });
```

Comment: Code only answers are discouraged. Please add some explanation as to how this solves the problem, or how this differs from the existing answers. [From Review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/late-answers/25188774)

Answer (score 1):

You can use any of these:

```
Intent i = new Intent(getActivity().getApplication(),SecondActivity.class);
```

or

```
Intent i = new Intent(getActivity(),SecondActivity.class);
```