# How can I call an intent from a fragment KOTLIN

Tags: android, android-intent, kotlin, fragment, onclicklistener

Calling an intent with onClick Listener from an activity is not a problem, but the same code in a fragment throws an unrechable code error in Intent that says none of its constructors can be called with these parameters. Here's my code:

class FragEqCrew : Fragment() {

```
override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
                          savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.frag_eq_crew, container, false)

    eq_row.setOnClickListener(({
        var clickintent = Intent(this@FragEqCrew, Equipment::class.java)
        startActivity(clickintent)

    }))

}
}
```

Comment: Because Fragment is not context. Use `getActivity()`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51576189/3001746

Comment: Harpreet Singh's comment is the solution. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

This is because you have added return statement in starting. That's why code after return is unreachable.

Comment: With all due respect: **This could have been a comment**