# How to send data sent by BLE Device in a fragment to a new activity for display and plotting graph in app?

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-intent, android-recyclerview

I am completely new to Android and just learned Object-oriented programming. My project requires me to build something on open-source code. I am really struggling with this special case. Two fragments are under activity_main, one of them is TerminalFragment. I added a menuItem (R.id.plot) in it and set if the user clicks this Item that will lead him from TerminalFragment to activity_main2. Due to receive(byte data) and TerminalFragment still on active, the data is still printing out by receiveText.append(TextUtil.toCaretString(msg, newline.length() != 0)); in activity_main.

Now, I want to convert the data to String and send it to activity_main2 for display in recyclerview and plotting graph.  I am trying to use putextra and getextra but not sure how to access data from getextra in activity_main2. In my testing, the recyclerview just showed "John". Is something missing in my method? Does anyone have a better idea? Much Appreciated.

TerminalFragment

```
package de.kai_morich.simple_bluetooth_le_terminal;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothAdapter;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothDevice;
import android.content.ComponentName;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.ServiceConnection;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.text.Editable;
import android.text.Spannable;
import android.text.SpannableStringBuilder;
import android.text.method.ScrollingMovementMethod;
import android.text.style.ForegroundColorSpan;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.widget.EditText;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;

public class TerminalFragment extends Fragment implements ServiceConnection, SerialListener {

    private MenuItem menuItem;
    private enum Connected { False, Pending, True }

    private String deviceAddress;
    private SerialService service;

    private TextView receiveText;
    private TextView sendText;
    private TextUtil.HexWatcher hexWatcher;

    private Connected connected = Connected.False;
    private boolean initialStart = true;
    private boolean hexEnabled = false;
    private boolean pendingNewline = false;
    private String newline = TextUtil.newline_crlf;
    private String output;

    /*
     * Lifecycle
     */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setHasOptionsMenu(true);
        //Register with activity
        // You must inform the system that your app bar fragment is participating in the population of the options menu.
        // tells the system that your fragment would like to receive menu-related callbacks.

        setRetainInstance(true);
        deviceAddress = getArguments().getString("device");
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        if (connected != Connected.False)
            disconnect();
        getActivity().stopService(new Intent(getActivity(), SerialService.class));
        super.onDestroy();
    }

    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        if(service != null)
            service.attach(this);
        else
            getActivity().startService(new Intent(getActivity(), SerialService.class)); // prevents service destroy on unbind from recreated activity caused by orientation change
    }

    @Override
    public void onStop() {
        if(service != null && !getActivity().isChangingConfigurations())
            service.detach();
        super.onStop();
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation") // onAttach(context) was added with API 23. onAttach(activity) works for all API versions
    @Override
    public void onAttach(@NonNull Activity activity) {
        super.onAttach(activity);
        getActivity().bindService(new Intent(getActivity(), SerialService.class), this, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDetach() {
        try { getActivity().unbindService(this); } catch(Exception ignored) {}
        super.onDetach();
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        if(initialStart && service != null) {
            initialStart = false;
            getActivity().runOnUiThread(this::connect);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName name, IBinder binder) {
        service = ((SerialService.SerialBinder) binder).getService();
        service.attach(this);
        if(initialStart && isResumed()) {
            initialStart = false;
            getActivity().runOnUiThread(this::connect);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName name) {
        service = null;
    }

    /*
     * UI
     */
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_terminal, container, false);
        receiveText = view.findViewById(R.id.receive_text);                          // TextView performance decreases with number of spans
        receiveText.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorRecieveText)); // set as default color to reduce number of spans
        receiveText.setMovementMethod(ScrollingMovementMethod.getInstance());

        sendText = view.findViewById(R.id.send_text);
        hexWatcher = new TextUtil.HexWatcher(sendText);
        hexWatcher.enable(hexEnabled);
        sendText.addTextChangedListener(hexWatcher);
        sendText.setHint(hexEnabled ? "HEX mode" : "");

        View sendBtn = view.findViewById(R.id.send_btn);
        sendBtn.setOnClickListener(v -> send(sendText.getText().toString()));
        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreateOptionsMenu(@NonNull Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_terminal, menu);
        menu.findItem(R.id.hex).setChecked(hexEnabled);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.clear) {
            receiveText.setText("");
            return true;
        } if (id == R.id.plot){
            Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), MainActivity2.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            //receive.;
            return true;
        }else if (id == R.id.newline) {
            String[] newlineNames = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.newline_names);
            String[] newlineValues = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.newline_values);
            int pos = java.util.Arrays.asList(newlineValues).indexOf(newline);
            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
            builder.setTitle("Newline");
            builder.setSingleChoiceItems(newlineNames, pos, (dialog, item1) -> {
                newline = newlineValues[item1];
                dialog.dismiss();
            });
            builder.create().show();
            return true;
        } else if (id == R.id.hex) {
            hexEnabled = !hexEnabled;
            sendText.setText("");
            hexWatcher.enable(hexEnabled);
            sendText.setHint(hexEnabled ? "HEX mode" : "");
            item.setChecked(hexEnabled);
            return true;
        } else {
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }

    /*
     * Serial + UI
     */
    private void connect() {
        try {
            BluetoothAdapter bluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
            BluetoothDevice device = bluetoothAdapter.getRemoteDevice(deviceAddress);
            status("connecting...");
            connected = Connected.Pending;
            SerialSocket socket = new SerialSocket(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), device);
            service.connect(socket);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            onSerialConnectError(e);
        }
    }

    private void disconnect() {
        connected = Connected.False;
        service.disconnect();
    }

    private void send(String str) {
        if(connected != Connected.True) {
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "not connected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return;
        }
        try {
            String msg;
            byte[] data;
            if(hexEnabled) {
                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                TextUtil.toHexString(sb, TextUtil.fromHexString(str));
                TextUtil.toHexString(sb, newline.getBytes());
                msg = sb.toString();
                data = TextUtil.fromHexString(msg);
            } else {
                msg = str;
                data = (str + newline).getBytes();
            }
            SpannableStringBuilder spn = new SpannableStringBuilder(msg + '\n');
            spn.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorSendText)), 0, spn.length(), Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
            receiveText.append(spn);
            service.write(data);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            onSerialIoError(e);
        }
    }

    private void receive(byte[] data) {
        if(hexEnabled) {
            receiveText.append("Hello" + TextUtil.toHexString(data) + '\n');
        } else {
            String msg = new String(data);
            if(newline.equals(TextUtil.newline_crlf) && msg.length() > 0) {
                // don't show CR as ^M if directly before LF
                msg = msg.replace(TextUtil.newline_crlf, TextUtil.newline_lf);
                // special handling if CR and LF come in separate fragments
                if (pendingNewline && msg.charAt(0) == '\n') {
                    Editable edt = receiveText.getEditableText();
                    if (edt != null && edt.length() > 1)
                        edt.replace(edt.length() - 2, edt.length(), "");
                }
                pendingNewline = msg.charAt(msg.length() - 1) == '\r';
            }
            receiveText.append(TextUtil.toCaretString(msg, newline.length() != 0)); //print out data
            output = receiveText.toString(); // CharSequence to String
            Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), MainActivity2.class);
            intent.putExtra("output",output); // send data to next activity, MainActivity2
        }
    }

    private void status(String str) {
        SpannableStringBuilder spn = new SpannableStringBuilder(str + '\n');
        spn.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorStatusText)), 0, spn.length(), Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
        receiveText.append(spn);
    }

    /*
     * SerialListener
     */
    @Override
    public void onSerialConnect() {
        status("connected");
        connected = Connected.True;
    }

    @Override
    public void onSerialConnectError(Exception e) {
        status("connection failed: " + e.getMessage());
        disconnect();
    }

    @Override
    public void onSerialRead(byte[] data) {// receive data
        receive(data); // send data to printout
    }

    @Override
    public void onSerialIoError(Exception e) {
        status("connection lost: " + e.getMessage());
        disconnect();
    }

}
```

MainActivity2.java (new activity)

```
package de.kai_morich.simple_bluetooth_le_terminal;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar;
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;
import androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager;
import androidx.fragment.app.FragmentTransaction;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.DefaultItemAnimator;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class MainActivity2 extends AppCompatActivity {

    Fragment CustomFragment;
    private ArrayList<Data> dataList;
    private RecyclerView recyclerView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2);
        Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar2);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.dataflow);
        dataList = new ArrayList<>();
        String data;
        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            Bundle extra = getIntent().getExtras();
            if (extra == null) {
                data = null;
                receiveData(data);
            } else {
                data = extra.getString("output");
                receiveData(data);
            }
        } else {
            data = (String) savedInstanceState.getSerializable("output");
            receiveData(data);
        }
        setAdapter();
    }

    private void receiveData(String data){
        String Data = data;
        dataList.add(new Data("John"));
        dataList.add(new Data(Data));
    }

    private void setAdapter() {
        recyclerAdapter adapter = new recyclerAdapter(dataList);
        RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getApplicationContext());
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
        recyclerView.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_plot, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.dataplot:
                Toast.makeText(this, "dataplot", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                replaceFragment(new DataPlotFragment());
                return true;
            case R.id.fft:
                Toast.makeText(this, "FFT", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                replaceFragment(new FftFragment());
                return true;
            case R.id.data:
                Toast.makeText(this, "DATA", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                finish();
                return true;
            default:
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }
    private void replaceFragment(Fragment fragment){

        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
        fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.plotframelayout,fragment);
        fragmentTransaction.commit();
    }


}
```

Comment: @Risto I rephrased my question and only put the important code instead of every detail.

Comment: Inside TerminalFragment try adding `intent.putExtra("your_key", "your_value")` before calling `startActivity()` and inside MainActivity2 try using `getStringExtra("the_same_key")` instead of `getExtra()` and let me know if it works.

Comment: @ganjaam I deleted the if statement of savedInstanceState == null and put String extra getIntent().getStringExtra(); directly into receive(). For TerminalFragment, I added intent.putExtra("output", "output") in if (id == R.id.plot) but deleted the code of last two lines in receive().

Comment: The recyclerView has shown: "John" <next line> "androidx.appcompat.widget.... "

Answer (score 0):

I realized I also need to add getText() in receive(). However, the recycler view won't update itself, it just captures what it has in the recyclerview of activity_main with TerminalFragment when the user click the menuItem (id,plot). Either getextrastring() or using bundle able to pass the data to Mainactivity2.
I think I need to add something else to keep adding data to the recyclerview of activity_main2 from activity_main.

onOptionsItemSelected of TerminalFragment

```
if (id == R.id.plot){
            Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), MainActivity2.class);
            intent.putExtra("output",output); //output
            startActivity(intent);
            return true;
        }
```

receive() of TerminalFragment

```
private void receive(byte[] data) {
        if(hexEnabled) {
            receiveText.append("Hello" + TextUtil.toHexString(data) + '\n');
        } else {
            String msg = new String(data);
            if(newline.equals(TextUtil.newline_crlf) && msg.length() > 0) {
                // don't show CR as ^M if directly before LF
                msg = msg.replace(TextUtil.newline_crlf, TextUtil.newline_lf);
                // special handling if CR and LF come in separate fragments
                if (pendingNewline && msg.charAt(0) == '\n') {
                    Editable edt = receiveText.getEditableText();
                    if (edt != null && edt.length() > 1)
                        edt.replace(edt.length() - 2, edt.length(), "");
                }
                pendingNewline = msg.charAt(msg.length() - 1) == '\r';
            }
            receiveText.append(TextUtil.toCaretString(msg, newline.length() != 0)); //print out data
            output = receiveText.getText().toString(); // CharSequence to String
        }
    }
```

OnCreate of mainActivity2

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2);
        Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar2);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.dataflow);
        dataList = new ArrayList<>();
        String data;
        Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
        if (extras != null)
        {
            data = extras.getString("output");
            receiveData(data);
        }
        setAdapter();
    }
```