# Getpreferences not working in fragment

Tags: android, android-studio, android-fragments, kotlin

Commands like `findViewById` ,  `getSharedPreferences` are not working inside `Fragment`
I am using kotlin and my code is as follow

```
fun update (v:View){
Val sharedpref = getSharedPreferences("logindata",Context.MODE_PRIVATE)}
```

LOG

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.techno.app, PID: 25691
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not find method update(View) in a parent or ancestor Context for android:onClick attribute defined on view class android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton
at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.resolveMethod(AppCompatViewInflater.java:327)
at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:284)
at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5721)
at android.widget.TextView.performClick(TextView.java:10936)
at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:22620)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
```

Comment: try using var instead of val.

Comment: It's `val`, not `Val`. `Val` is not a type, but simply used for variable (to be more accurate: value) declarations. Kotlin then uses type inference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thou concept wise the above answer (https://stackoverflow.com/a/44469679/3845798) is correct, but there it needs to be in Kotlin. Like `getActivity()`, `getView()` will be access like a property.
Also, its `val` not `Val`.

Here is simple example of how to use `findViewById()`, `getSharedPreferences()` inside the activity.

**MainActivity Code -**

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        setBaseFragment()
    }


    private fun setBaseFragment() {
        val fragment = MainFragment.newInstance()
        supportFragmentManager
                .beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.fragment_container, fragment)
                .commit()
    }
}
```

**And this is my fragment Class**

```
class MainFragment : Fragment() {

    lateinit var show: Button
    lateinit var save: Button
    lateinit var text: TextView

    var prefs: SharedPreferences? = null

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    }

    override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater?, container: ViewGroup?,
                              savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
        return inflater!!.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false)
    }

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

        show = view?.findViewById(R.id.showButton) as Button
        save = view?.findViewById(R.id.saveButton) as Button
        text = view?.findViewById(R.id.textResult) as TextView

        prefs =    activity.getSharedPreferences("FUN",MODE_PRIVATE)


        save.setOnClickListener {
            val editor = prefs!!.edit()
            editor.putString("Saving", "This is saveValueFromSharedPref")
            editor.apply()
        }

        show.setOnClickListener {
            text.setText(prefs?.getString("Saving","NotSaved"))
        }
    }

    companion object {
        fun newInstance(): MainFragment {
            val fragment = MainFragment()
            return fragment
        }
    }
}
```

It's a simple example with a text and two button.

First you have to save and show.

Also, for your app crash you can check [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18896666/3845798).

Answer (score 2):

You are calling a `Context` object in `Fragment`, Fragment is not a `Context`.so change this line to something like this:

```
Val sharedpref = getActivity().getSharedPreferences("logindata",Context.MODE_PRIVATE)}
```

And use `getView` method in `onCreateView` for using `findViewById`, for example:

```
TextView tv = (TextView) getView().findViewById(R.id.mtTextview);
```

Comment: I did what you said,therefore no error is shown in studio but when i run application in android phone it stops working when i open that fragment

Comment: add crash log here

Comment: How to get crash log

Comment: In android studio ,`tools/android/android device monitor` from devices tab choose your device, then in `logcat` section hit `add` button and, set a name for your app in `filter name`  and add your package name in `by application name`. run your app and see the crash reports. and if you are using another IDE then search in google about how to get app log in your IDE

Comment: Here it is https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B7rSAlu3yCjUSDZiUUJraURSajA/view?usp=drivesdk

Comment: Brother you are telling the answer for java but i am using kotlin to create my project

Comment: I do not know much about `kotlin` but the process should be the same

Comment: Yeah process will be same but code will be different