# How To implement onClick in Fragments?

Tags: android, xml, android-studio

I am implementing navigation drawer, I need to handle an `onClick` method from a fragment, how can I achieve this?. In Mainactivity.java this can be performed easily but when I use fragments it's not possible to use `findViewbyid`?

Thank You

Comment: Please post some code for your fragment

Comment: No will can help you without any code sample, need more info

Comment: Duplicate : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14139774/android-app-crashing-fragment-and-xml-onclick

Answer (score 2):

In fragment, you can simply use View to handle buttons in Fragment.

```
View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.yourFragment, container, false);
myButton = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.myButton);
myButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        //Some code...
    }
});
return view;
```

Comment: he omplementd **navigation drawer** not **bottom navigation**

Comment: Sorry for my misunderstood, so i hope my second code will help him. Now i will update my answer.