# How to create custom Popup Menu using Kotlin in AndroidStudio?

Tags: android, kotlin, popupmenu

I am trying to create popup menu similarly like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21329132/2462531) on click on a button view in Android using Koltin. I searched for SOF and Google didn't find any suggestions. Can anyone provide a sample code to achieve it using kotlin.

Comment: Kotlin is just a language. You'll find plenty examples in Java, I suggest you, at least, understand both. Once you understand what the code does, then you can play with different languages and syntaxes.

Comment: Yeah, I agree with you, but there are no examples using Kotlin language.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Finally, I did it, It may help someone

Step 1. First, create an `activity_main.xml` contains a button named `my_button`

Step 2. Then take `header_menu.xml` under `res/menu`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item
        android:id="@+id/header1"
        android:title="H1" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/header2"
        android:title="H2" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/header3"
        android:title="H3" />

</menu>
```

Step 3. Finally, in `MainActivity.kt` use it like:

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        my_button.setOnClickListener {
             showPopup(my_button)
          }
    }

    private fun showPopup(view: View) {
        val popup = PopupMenu(this, view)
        popup.inflate(R.menu.header_menu)

        popup.setOnMenuItemClickListener(PopupMenu.OnMenuItemClickListener { item: MenuItem? ->

            when (item!!.itemId) {
                R.id.header1 -> {
                    Toast.makeText(this@MainActivity, item.title, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                }
                R.id.header2 -> {
                    Toast.makeText(this@MainActivity, item.title, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                }
                R.id.header3 -> {
                    Toast.makeText(this@MainActivity, item.title, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                }
            }

            true
        })

        popup.show()
    }
```

Comment: What would the code look like if I wanted to open a fragment for one of the popup menu actions?

Comment: @Dan Can you post it as new question instead.

Comment: @Dan call this util method from Activity like this:

`ActivityUtil.addFragmentToActivity(
        getSupportFragmentManager(), fragment, R.id.frag_container);`

Answer (score 5):

Following Kotlin's *nice and clean principle*:
You can do this as well:

1)in your .xml file: *(but "onClick" in xml can be used while  doing java as well)*

```
<Button 
  ........
  android:onClick="showPopUp"
  ....../>
```

2)in your .kt file: *(using kotlin's lambda expression)*

```
fun showPopUp(view: View) {
    val popupMenu = PopupMenu(this, view)
    val inflater = popupMenu.menuInflater
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.header_menu, popupMenu.menu)
    popupMenu.show()

    popupMenu.setOnMenuItemClickListener {
        when(it.itemId) {
            R.id.header1 -> {
                Toast.makeText(this@MainActivity, item.title, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            R.id.header2 -> {
                Toast.makeText(this@MainActivity, item.title, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            R.id.header3 -> {
                Toast.makeText(this@MainActivity, item.title, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            ...........
        }
        true
    }
}
```

Comment: Setting the  method in xml only appears to work if the method is in an Activity, not a fragment. https://stackoverflow.com/a/18896666/211292

Answer (score 2):

for people who hate xml:

```kotlin
    private fun showOverflowMenu(context: Context, anchor: View) {
        val menu = PopupMenu(context, anchor)

        menu.menu.apply {
            add("Rename").setOnMenuItemClickListener {
                // TODO rename
                true
            }
            add("change context").setOnMenuItemClickListener {
                // change stuff
                true
            }

            add("delete").setOnMenuItemClickListener {
                // TODO delete some stuff
                true
            }
        }

        menu.show()
    }
```