# How to resolve NumberFormatException: Empty string, while working in android without using any try and catch exception handler?

Tags: java, android

When I run this program i get the error Exception in thread "main" 
java.lang.NumberFormatException: empty String. Is it possible to make 
this work?Could we import diff projects into a single project?
When I run this program i get the error Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: empty String. Is it possible to make this wor

```
package com.example.nav1;

import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

public  class SgpaActivity extends Fragment  {
@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable 
ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View rootview = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_sgpa, container, 
false);
 //       onButtonClick(view);

    EditText e1,e2,e3,e4,e5,e6 =null;
    e1 = e2 =e3 = e4 =e5 =e6;
    TextView t1 = null;
    float num1=0;
    e1 =  rootview.findViewById(R.id.e1);
    e2 = rootview.findViewById(R.id.e2);
    e3 = rootview.findViewById(R.id.e3);
    e4 = rootview.findViewById(R.id.e4);
    e5 = rootview.findViewById(R.id.e5);
    e6 = rootview.findViewById(R.id.e6);
    t1 = rootview.findViewById(R.id.result);
if(e1!=null)
    num1 = Float.parseFloat(e1.getText().toString());
    float num2 = Float.parseFloat(e2.getText().toString());
    float num3 = Float.parseFloat(e3.getText().toString());
    float num4 = Float.parseFloat(e4.getText().toString());
    float num5 = Float.parseFloat(e5.getText().toString());
    float num6 = Float.parseFloat(e6.getText().toString());
    float sum = 0;
    sum = (num1*25) + (num2*25) + (num3*25) + (num4*25) + (num5*23) + 
(num6*23) ;
    float cgpa = sum/(25+25+25+25+23+23);
    t1.setText(Float.toString(cgpa));

    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_sgpa, container,false);
}

public void onButtonClick (View v)
{  // return inflater.inflate(R.layout.article_view, container, false);
}

}

I expect the output of 1 , 1, 1, 1, 1,1 be 1
```

Comment: Why can't you use a try/catch handler?

Comment: in `onCreateView` are the `EditText` fields going to have any numeric value?  Maybe you should be doing `num1 = Float.parseFloat(e1.getText().toString());` etc in  `onButtonClick `

Comment: You could use a Ternary Operator as your argument for all the **Float.parseFloat()** methods, for example: `num1 = Float.parseFloat((e1.getText().toString().matches("-?\\d+(\\.\\d+)?") ? e1.getText().toString() : "0.0"));`. If **e1** contains nothing (Null String) or contains anything other than a signed/unsigned Integer or decimal  value then "0.0" is supplied as the argument for the **parseFloat()**  method otherwise the actual numerical value in **e1** is supplied.

Comment: Unclear what you're really asking here. Just catch the exception and substitute a default or error value. No need to pre-validate it @DevilsHnd: this is just wasted code, and possibly code that disagrees with what `parseFloat()` accepts.

Comment: @user207421 - I thought the title of this post was quite clear: `without using any try and catch exception handler`

Comment: have updated the answer ,  hope it helps to resolve the issue now.

Answer (score 0):

When you are using the `android:onClick` attribute for a button inside a fragment in that case you need to define the function inside the calling activity  .

As suggested here : -
[onClick attribute in fragment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14139774/android-app-crashing-fragment-and-xml-onclick)

Or

Try implementing the OnClickListner for the button.

Inside the method , do all your validation before setting the answer.

As specified earlier in the comments ,  **the exception is thrown if** :-

> NullPointerException - if the string is null
>
> NumberFormatException - if the string does not contain a parsable  float.

**How to avoid it:-**

1. Either you use a regression check as specified [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3543749/7200713).
2. If you can ok with double , then try this:- [Doubles.tryParse(String)](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/18.0/api/docs/com/google/common/primitives/Doubles.html#tryParse(java.lang.String)) 
   by Google's Guava library as answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22936891/7200713) .
3. Or rather than checking again and again ,you can directly try setting the  digits to be allowed as input in the edittext by setting this:-

   `android:digits="0123456789."`

This [link](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3543729/7200713) as few  good answers for the issue.

Answer (score 0):

First check if your string is not empty using `TextUtils.isEmpty()`, If string is not empty then check if it contains valid float data using regex.

```
if(!TextUtils.isEmpty(e1.getText().toString())){
    if (text.matches("[0-9]*\\.?[0-9]+") {
        num1 = Float.parseFloat(e1.getText().toString());
    } else {
        //Toast invalid number
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would surround it with a `try` and `catch` block . The reason for this is because the string might not be **null** , but it might be empty or you might find a character that is not a number . Therefore :

```
try{
   float something = Float.parseFloat(e1.getText().toString());
}catch(NumberFormatException e){
   e.printStackTrace();
}catch(NullPointerException e){
  e.printStackTrace();
}
```

That's because you don't need to ask if it is **null** , or if it is empty or if it doesn't contain characters .

Answer (score -1):

I think the error is

```
num1 = Float.parseFloat(e1.getText().toString());
```

because

`e1.getText().toString()` is empty.

Comment: final String numStr = e1.getText().toString();      if (numStr.length() > 0) num1 = Float.parseFloat(numStr);

Comment: I tried using try and catch statements , they seem to work but not getting how to use onbuttonclick  method in fragments. Keeps showing this error     java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not find method onButtonClick(View) in a parent or ancestor Context for android:onClick attribute defined on view class android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton with id 'button'

Comment: You can use this Button btn = rootview.findViewById(R.id.your_button_id); btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener())